# How do you ask 2 paralleling things if exist?

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to ask,

> Why is there Chinglish and why is not there English style Chinese?

Or

> Why is there Chinglish but is not there English style Chinese?

What is the correct way to say that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Why is there Chinglish, and why is there no English-style Chinese?
- Why is there Chinglish but no English-style Chinese?
- Why is there Chinglish when there is no English-style Chinese?

Any of these is valid.  The first is two independent questions; the other two emphasize the contrast.

Note that I used *no* rather than *not*.  I am not sure why my preference is so strong.  I guess I might use *not* to express absence (no such thing in an expected place) rather than nonexistence (no such thing anywhere).

Comment: Great answer!!!!